# React Native Device Display

Tags: ios, react-native

i used react-native-display library on my project, but whenever I build in xcode it gives me an error of Unable to resolve module Dimension. I do steps on their documentation but it still gives me an error.

```
'use strict';`
var React = require('react-native');
var Display = require('react-native-device-display');
var {
StyleSheet } = React;
```

When I click build, this error "Unable to resolve module Dimension" display

Here's the link to the library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-device-display

Comment: We can't fix what we can't see - post the actual error AND code causing the error.

Comment: Hi Marc, actually I havent yet put anycode regarding the library I just require the library then click build.

Comment: Where did you put the code you mentioned?

Comment: What version of react-native are you using?

Comment: this is the react version in my package.json "react-native": "^0.14.1"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A late reply, but useful as a reference: this is related to an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3817) in React Native 0.14+ (and still open as of RN 0.16/0.17).

In this case, the issue is triggered by the react-native-device-display's package creator using a specific require to Dimensions in one of his files. Refer to [this PR](https://github.com/kkjdaniel/react-native-device-display/pull/16/files) which contains a workaround for this particular repo.

To generalize this issue: similar errors may also occur on other RN components/extensions; in this case, find where the module(s) is/are being imported in the code, and convert any problematic pure "require" statement into a destructuring assignment from `require('react-native')`, eg convert

```
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions') // will fail
```

to

```
var { Dimensions , other vars you need} = require('react-native') // will work
```